# Как можно переиспользовать повторяющиеся экраны в storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

Есть задача создать программу с разными flow. Например, создать аккаунт, мой профиль, главный экран, создать заказ. Логично что под каждый flow и его состояния/экраны я могу создать view controllers в storyboard

В этих разных частях flow есть экраны которые повторяются. Например, экран "Добавить кредитную карточку" повторяется в таких местах/flow:

- создать аккаунт
- мой профиль
- создать ордер

Во всех трех разных местах программы по факту можно создать 3 разных экрана "добавить кредитку". Но по логике вещей я понимаю что выгоднее такой экран создать один раз и потом просто переиспользовать во всех трех местах.

Но я не могу понять как это можно сделать.

Т.е. как можно один раз создать такой View Controller и классы для него (.h .m) это я понимаю.

А вот как один такой viewcontroller переиспользовать в разные местах в зависимости от контекста - не могу понять

Заранее благодарен за помощь

Comment: почему бы не показывать его модально?

Answer (score 2):

Первый способ, просто перетаскиваете экшены (нажатие кнопки, тап по ячейки) от одного экрана к этому и указывается соответсвующие индентификаторы. Далее в коде контроллера, от которого происходит переход, в методе `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` определять идентификатор и передавать нужные данные в контроллер.

Второй способ, в сториборде указывается Storyboard ID, и из другого контроллера создается этот контроллер         `storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Indentificator")`, выполняется переход на него.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую в данном случае не использовать Storyboard, а создать эти экраны в коде. Тогда вы сможете на любом экране обратится к классу-"конструктору" и мгновенно отрисовать нужные вам экраны без лишнего кода.
Кроме того, у вас есть вариант использовать отдельный UIView в xib файле, но события к нему придется подключать через делегаты или нотификации.